# Sublime text goto anything configuration?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

are you maybe aware of any way to configure the goto anything feature of sublime text (cmd+P)? In particular, I would like to restrict  suggestions only to a specific folder within a sublime text project. Is it possible?

As a (almost) died project, I prefer to ask here than the official forums. I guess a really lot of us do use ST.
I googled for this question but found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 settings that can do this:

- `folder_exclude_patterns`: exclude *folders* from the sidebar *and* from the goto anything
- `file_exclude_patterns`: exclude *files* from the sidebar *and* from the goto anything
- `binary_file_patterns`: exclude from the goto anything **only**.

Comment: i tried, I knew them but they seem not to be honored when using the GoTo search.

Comment: What value did you set, to which one, and what did you get?